# How do I remove old artisan command from Kernel in Laravel 5

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-artisan

I have created some Command files into my Laravel Application. Laravel version is 5.2. I set command like: `get:email` in the Command file. Also call the Command file into `Kernel.php`. After that I can see the artisan command list by typing the command `php artisan list`. as like as below:

```
//output
get:email
```

And I changed the command title `get:email` to `get-bq:email`. When I run the command `php artisan get-bq:email` -- its working nicely. Also I can see the list by typing the command `php artisan list`::

```
//output
get-bq:email
```

**Issue / Problem**: Both commands are working. But I won't to work with both of them. I have done the following things:

1. modified command file as well as command
2. run `composer dump-autoload -o`
3. run `composer update`
4. remove vendor and storage folder then run `composer update` again.

Still the old command is working into my system.

**What I want**: How May I remove my old commands from my Laravel(5.2) application?

Answer (score 4):

Run these commands:

```
php artisan cache:clear
php artisan config:clear
```

These commands will clear app cache and config cache and recreate it.

Comment: Same Problem :: working both. can not remove old one. Still working both:: `php artisan get-bq:email` and `php artisan get:email`

Comment: Did you solve a problem?  If not, try `php artisan config:clear`.

Comment: I did not find any solution. I used `php artisan config:clear` :: its not clearing old

Answer (score 1):

I've had the same problem recently.

Repoeatedly tried

```
php artisan cache:clear
php artisan config:clear
```

and the cached Kernal command wouldn't clear.

In desperation i killed the queue worker terminal and restarted the queue with the command

```
php artisan queue:work
```

The issue stopped.